# Long paths with Python 2.7 and Windows Server 2016

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-2.7, windows-server-2016

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365797/python-long-filename-support-broken-in-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557760/long-paths-in-python-on-windows), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963302/how-to-append-to-the-front-of-a-file-path-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) about how to get python (2.x) working with long paths on Windows. On the other hand, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489473/4480139) post comes to the conclusion that it is not possible with Python 2.7.

My setup:

- Windows Server 2016 Version `1607` build `14393.969`
- The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
  registry keys are to `1` and I rebooted
- Python 2.7 64 bit

The code I am struggling with is this:

```
my_long_path = u'\\\\?\\c:\\Users\\asdf\\Desktop\\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\'
os.makedirs(my_long_path)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 132, line 1
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: u'\\\\?\\c:\\Users\\..
```

- Is it possible to work with long paths on Windows 2016 and Python
  2.7?
- Is it possible with Windows 2016 Server and Python 3.7?
- Is it possible with Windows 10 and Python 2.7?
- Is it really possible with
  Windows 10 and Python 3.7 (as indicated in one of the above mentioned
  post)?